# How to de-duplicate records using INSERT INTO... SELECT... FROM...in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

There:
 i) are two tables a) "incidents_all" and "incidents" and a sequence "incident_ids".
ii) table, incidents has an extra column id as primary key constraint, than that of table, incidents_all.
iii) "incidents_all" contains duplicate records.
**Objective:** To insert unique incident records into table, "incidents" from table, "incidents_all" along with the sequence number.

I am trying to insert unique records, as follows:
a) Create Unique Index on the columns on which uniqueness required, using:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "evnt_time_hst_flt_code_idx"  ON "incidents"
(
"host_name",
"down_since",
"fault_code"
);
```

b) Populate "incidents" table with unique records by selecting sequence number from "ids" along with records from "incidents_all".

```
INSERT INTO "incidents"
(
"id",
"sl_no",
"host_name"
"down_since",
"category",
"fault_code"
)
SELECT
"incident_ids".NEXTVAL AS "id",
"incidents_all"."sl_no" AS "sl_no",
"incidents_all"."host_name" AS "host_name",
"incidents_all"."down_since" AS "down_since",
"incidents_all"."category" AS "category",
"incidents_all"."fault_code" AS "fault_code"
FROM "incidents_all", "incident_ids";
```

But, getting Oracle exception, "Sequence Not Allowed Here!".

Please guide me in inserting unique records along with sequence number!

Comment: without "ids" in from clausule

Comment: value of which column is repeated in "incidents_all" table?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use lower case table names and columns?

Comment: remove *IDS* from *FROM* clause.

Comment: Keeping aside the problem of the sequence, how should this remove duplicates? You are inserting into a new table all the rows of your starting tables, including duplicates. If you want to remove duplicates, you may need to apply some filter and/or aggregation. Please post your table structure and an example of starting data and needed result to clarify the logic to use in removing duplicates.

Comment: Hi Negative Voter, please read the objective for clarification!

Comment: Say you have 2 rows with equal values of `host_name down_since, fault_code` and different values in `id, sl_no, category`. Given that in the new table `id` should be filled with a sequence, what about `sl_no` and `category`? Do you want a max value, a min, a random one?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
INSERT INTO "incidents"
(
"id",
"sl_no",
"host_name"
"down_since",
"category",
"fault_code"
)
SELECT
"ids".NEXTVAL AS "id",
"incidents_all"."sl_no" AS "sl_no",
"incidents_all"."host_name" AS "host_name",
"incidents_all"."down_since" AS "down_since",
"incidents_all"."category" AS "category",
"incidents_all"."fault_code" AS "fault_code"
FROM "incidents_all";
```

You don't need to include sequence in from clause.

Comment: Even if this solves the error, it does not do what the OP needs, that is removing duplicates from a table

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
INSERT INTO "incidents"
(
"id",
"sl_no",
"host_name"
"down_since",
"category",
"fault_code"
)
SELECT
incident_ids.NEXTVAL AS "id",   -- ->!!!!
"incidents_all"."sl_no" AS "sl_no",
"incidents_all"."host_name" AS "host_name",
"incidents_all"."down_since" AS "down_since",
"incidents_all"."category" AS "category",
"incidents_all"."fault_code" AS "fault_code"
FROM "incidents_all";
```

If you want the next value of a sequence then you must use sequence_name.nextval.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a table with duplicated values, based on columns `a, b` and another one, with the same structure, where you want to insert non duplicated values.

```
create table duplicateTable(id number, a number, b number, c number);
create table uniqueTable ( id number primary key, a number, b number, c number);
```

Say you want to use a sequence for the id of the second table

```
create sequence id_seq start with 1;
```

Assuming data like the following

```
insert into duplicateTable(id, a, b, c) values (1, 100, 50, 1000);
insert into duplicateTable(id, a, b, c) values (2, 100, 50, 2000);
insert into duplicateTable(id, a, b, c) values (3, 100, 99, 9000);
insert into duplicateTable(id, a, b, c) values (4, 999, 50, 7777);
insert into duplicateTable(id, a, b, c) values (5, 999, 99, 0);
```

you have to decide how to handle the columns that does not belong to your unique key; for example, assuming that you want to avoid duplicates based on a key on `a, b` and that you want to get the maximum value of `c` for a given couple `(a, b)`, you can use:

```
insert into uniqueTable ( id, a, b, c)
select id_seq.nextVal, a, b, c
from (
        select a, b, max(c) as c
        from duplicateTable
        group by a, b
     )

SQL> select * from uniqueTable;

        ID          A          B          C
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1        999         99          0
         2        100         50       2000
         3        100         99       9000
         4        999         50       7777
```

Comment: For clarification, table, "incidents" has an extra column "id" as primary key constraint, than that of table, "incidents_all".

Comment: @AVA This should work well in this case. Edited to show it

Answer (score 0):

Referring, http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_packages_dbms_errlog.htm and answer of Bhavesh Ghodasara,

a) Create error logging table:

```
CREATE TABLE err$_log_table
  (
    ora_err_number$ NUMBER,
    ora_err_mesg$ VARCHAR2(2000),
    ora_err_rowid$ rowid,
    ora_err_optyp$ VARCHAR2(2),
    ora_err_tag$   VARCHAR2(2000)
  );
```

b) Populate "incidents" table with records from "incidents_all" and selecting sequence number from "ids":

```
INSERT INTO "incidents"
(
"id",
"sl_no",
"host_name"
"down_since",
"category",
"fault_code"
)
SELECT
"incident_ids".NEXTVAL AS "id",
"incidents_all"."sl_no" AS "sl_no",
"incidents_all"."host_name" AS "host_name",
"incidents_all"."down_since" AS "down_since",
"incidents_all"."category" AS "category",
"incidents_all"."fault_code" AS "fault_code"
FROM "incidents_all"
LOG ERRORS INTO err$_log_table ('duplicate') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

which adds unique records to table "incidents" and logs errors in table, err$_log_table whenever duplicate records encountered.